# Omxplayer subtitle problem on RPi 3 with Ubuntu Mate OS

Tags: omxplayer

Like you can see from the title I have problems with subtitles in omxplayer. Basically there are 2 problems.

First is that all non-english (like č, š, ž) letters are missing in subtitle text. Not that there is some other symbol or white-space in their place.

Second problem is not really a problem but more like personal preference. The subtitles are left-aligned instead of being centred.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For subtitle position I have found the solution. Basically there is command line argument when lunching omxplayer `--align center`. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and will share it here if someone  needs it later. Problem is that Omxplayer only supports UTF-8 encoding and the subtitles in question are encoded with windows-1250. To convert the encodings `iconv` can be used. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and write:

```
iconv -f windows-1250 -t UTF-8 path/to/file/subtitle_file.srt
```

Of course `iconv` can do much more than just these encodings. To learn more write `iconv --help` or `man iconv` in terminal.

I have to give credits to @CrazyLemon from local forum in our country, that pointed out that the encoding is the problem. Before that I suspected the font.